# Windows iot app updates.

Tags: updates, windowsiot

I am in the digital signage business for small businesses. We have created an app that runs digital signage through the raspberry pi using Windows iot. Everything works great but what if one day we wanted to make changes to the app. Is there a way to update the app without having to manually do it on site. I would prefer having the app do it programmically through regular checks but I'm not finding anything. Wish there was a App Store mechanism for the pi to update apps. Any ideas on this?

Comment: I am also looking for this functionality, but can't find any documentation on it. And it's been quite a few months

Answer (score 1):

All devices running Windows IoT Core run a small webserver instance on port 8080.  You can reach this by visiting http://DEVICEIPADDRESS:8080

The default credentials are:
U:Administrator 
P:p@ssw0rd

Within the portal, you can provision and deploy apps remotely using the App Manager by selecting "Apps" along the left-hand pane.

[image]

If you setup firewall rules to allow outbound traffic to the Windows IoT Core device you may be able to deploy updates remotely.

Comment: I know how to do that. I want the app to update itself. Not manually have to do it. There is no store or anything that could update the app. It be nice to have our own updater to our own IOT apps.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no app store for windows iot but it is possible to create your own. You could implement this functionality using a push or pull system with Azure.

Push - azure pushes updates to the devices.

Pull - the device asks azure for updates

[Get started with Event Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted/) (tutorial describing how to implement Event Hubs in Azure)

Another option could be to write your own REST API on a server (Azure or your own server).

Comment: He means updating the application code, not pushing data. Or do you realise that? In which case, what would I do with an .apx once I download it? Can i install it programmatically?